# Mac Pycharm Interpreter not working

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I can't run my python programs in **pycharm**. I installed `python3`, `pycharm` and `anaconda`. I can open the project and write python code, but can't run the program in pycharm. I can use the terminal to run my program and it works fine. Any ideas how to use the right interpreter? Where can I find it? BTW I work with a mac.

When I try to add an interpreter I can add an Virtualenv Environment, `Conda Environment` or System Interpreter. When I click on System interpreter and choose one, it wont work. I tried to find my python version with the terminal and use it in pycharm, but it wont do anything.

Thats what I see:
[entire screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj8cE.png)

The icon also seems weird (red cross):
[weird icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rztc4.png)

Greetings, Stefan

Comment: Have you tried setting the interpreter in Preferences > Project Interpreter?

Comment: I did, but it still doesnt work. I tried a few "interpreter" but none worked, maybe because they weren't interpreters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect your `conda` python installation via:

```
$ conda info
```

Mine is: `/root/miniconda`, so basic grepping shows what `python`s do I have:

```
root@d03107c14a07:/notebook# ls -al /root/miniconda/bin/ | grep python
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root root     129 Apr 16 16:20 ipython
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root root     129 Apr 16 16:20 ipython2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       9 Apr 16 16:20 python -> python2.7
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root root    1689 Apr 16 16:20 python-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       9 Apr 16 16:20 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root root   10302 Dec 21  2016 python2.7
```

And running it like below shows it works:

```
root@d03107c14a07:/notebook# /root/miniconda/bin/python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>>
```

We have the path, for me it's: `/root/miniconda/bin/python`

So, as we have it localized, we need to set it up with our Pycharm.

Go to `Settings`/`Preferences` and into `Project interpreter`, choose a settings wheel and `Add` - On the left you've got three options, choose Conda, your env might be found automatically, but if it isn't then you have the path to paste ;)

[Official docs ref](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)

[conda info ref](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-info.html)